# Design - Pointer to vector as access for class?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have this situation in "global" scope:

```
vector <Cell> mCells;// container for objects
CellEditor *mEditor; // instance of editor
```

and in editor, there is empty pointer, which is set during initialization like this:

```
mEditor->cells = &mCells;
```

and now I'm able to access the vector directly in class CodeEditor and do all editing directly to elements in vector. It seems to work well. Code seems to be cleaner and more general.

Now my question is more theoretical: **is this approach normal? Or are there some pitfalls lingering around some corner I'm not seeing now?**

Comment: the "global" scope is a really deep pitfall. You don't know in which order global resources will be allocated and initialized.

Comment: Oh my god... Please just... don't.

Comment: If `mCells` is global, so why do you need to pass its pointer to an object? The main pitfall is that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should probably add more code and explain situation. I'm writing this in Cinder, and it's internal structure is basically one main class with methods setup(), update() and draw(). So by "global" I meant members of this class. And because I thought it would be more cleaner and general to have editor handling all editing through pointer rather than having a ton of getters and setters placed all around.